# why div scroll didnt start in bottom

Tags: jquery, laravel

I have div with scroll and i want it to start in bottom. I have read some question here and search in google but i cant use it. this is my jquery code it start in bottom but when i scrolled it will always back in bottom.so i remove the the set interval and i just call the function but the scroll start in top again. I used code that i see here but its not working. guys help me

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  function updateScroll(){
  var element = document.getElementById("msgss");
  element.scrollTop = element.scrollHeight;
}
setInterval(updateScroll,1000);

</script>
```

and is my div tag

```
<div class="col-md-6 convo" id="msgss">
  <chat-log :messages="messages"></chat-log>
  <chat-composer v-on:messagesent="addmessage"></chat-composer>
</div>
```

Comment: Instead of scrolling to the bottom at a given interval, have you tried ensuring that the page has completely loaded (including the messages) before moving the scroll to the bottom?

Comment: yes its completely loaded sir.

Comment: the jquery code in the top is working sir but the problem is when i scroll it to the top it keeps returning to the bottom

Comment: it will keep returning to the bottom every 1 sec (1000ms) since that's what it was set to.

Comment: so i remove that set interval. when i remove it then the scroll didnt start in bottom its start on top. i try to call the function but still it starts in top

Comment: it is possible the by the time `updateScroll` is called, `element.scrollHeight` does not have the correct value yet. Adding a "delay" of 1sec via `setInterval` fixes that but the problem is that it continues to keep calling `updateScroll` every second.

Comment: okay . can you tell how to get the value of scrollHeight

Comment: Using `setInterval` is not a delay. You should use `setTimeout`.

Comment: I used it also. But idont know if its right i code it like this. setTimeout(updatescroll); is this right?

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure how `laravel` loads the `:messages="messages"` element but can you try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        updateScroll();
    });

    function updateScroll(){
        var element = document.getElementById("msgss");
        element.scrollTop = element.scrollHeight;
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
 $(window).load(function() {
  $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 1000);
 });
```